# How to reload a view after an async request passing data to a view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

How do i reload a view controller after making an async request when passing data, so that the data passed to a UILabel will be updated with the new value when ever the data is available.

This is the function that get the response from the API am using

```
let searchResultsData: AnyObject = []

func JSONAPIResults(results: AnyObject) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.searchResultsData = results
// This will output an object in the form 
// { offer: 12345,
/// currency: USD
 //}
    })
}
```

So, when i make a prepareForSegue call to new a view controller like this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showOffer") {
        if self.searchResultsData.count != 0 {
            (segue.destinationViewController as OfferViewController).toPass = currency
        }
    }
}
```

i want to pass the value of currency into the new view controller... but the response from the async request always delay like up to 5seconds before it returns, but by then the segue has already push to new the new view controller. 
So i need to a way to refresh the view controller to update the value.... Or is there a way around it other than reloading the new view controller

Comment: Please give us some code that explains what you are trying to do. What did you try and what went wrong? How are you trying? Then maybe we can help you.

Comment: I have updated the question with codes for clarity @Ulas Sancak

Comment: Why aren't you waiting for response to push the segue?

Comment: How do i wait for the response before pushing segue @Ulas Sancak

Comment: Where exactly are you performing the segue in the code? Please share it too.
You should perform the segue in the block where you get the response.

Comment: i have tried using performSegueForIdentifier but it's not working

Comment: You did not answer my question. Where and when exactly are you performing?

Comment: I am performing the segue before the response comes back from the async request

Comment: So don't do it. Wait for response. When you perform in the response block what exactly happens? prepareForSegue method is not being called?

Comment: prepareForSegue is not called in the response block

Comment: I am sorry but I can't help you. You are not giving enough information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Where i was having an issue is that the button that will fire the async request was also the one responsible for pushing into the new view controller.

Let say i have viewController1 and viewController2

So, i was able to detect the fault and instead create a connection between viewController1 and viewController2, say i call the connection 'showOffer'

And in the JSONAPIResults function i make a call to

```
 self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showOffer", sender: nil)
```

Lastly, the prepareForSegue still look the same.
That was how i was able to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

TRY:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
                    // get data here

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                        // update label here                        
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround (sorry no time to test it) : in your first ViewController declare an optional class variable typed function that takes array and return void. In OfferViewController implement function that takes array of any object and return void then in prepare for segue initialize declared class variable with newly function of OfferViewController and call that function on JSONAPIResults method. Probably your code should look something similar like this:

```
//first view controller
var updateFunction : ((searchResultsData:[AnyObject]) -> Void)?

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showOffer") {
        updateFunction = (segue.destinationViewController as OfferViewController).updateFunction
    }
} 

func JSONAPIResults(results: AnyObject) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.searchResultsData = results
        if(self.updateFunction != nil){
            self.updateFunction(searchResultsData)
        }
    })
}

//OfferViewController

func udpateFunction(searchResultsData:[AnyObject]){
    //update all views that need to be updated with values of searchResultsData
}
```